# How to grep only two words in a line in file between them specific number of random words present

Tags: linux, grep

Given a file with this content:

```
Feb 1 ohio a1 rambo
Feb 1 ny   a1 sandy
Feb 1 dc   a2 rambo
Feb 2 alpht a1 jazzy
```

I only want the count of those lines containing `Feb 1` and `rambo`.

Comment: rambo is actually not the last word in the line

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `awk` to do this more efficiently:

```
$ awk '/Feb 1/ && /rambo/' file
Feb 1 ohio a1 rambo
Feb 1 dc   a2 rambo
```

To count matches:

```
$ awk '/Feb 1/ && /rambo/ {sum++} END{print sum}' file
2
```

#### Explanation

- `awk '/Feb 1/ && /rambo/'` is saying: match all lines in which both `Feb 1` and `rambo` are matched. When this evaluates to True, awk performs its default behaviour: print the line.
- `awk '/Feb 1/ && /rambo/ {sum++} END{print sum}'` does the same, only that instead of printing the line, increments the var `sum`. When the file has been fully scanned, it enters in the `END` block, where it prints the value of the var `sum`.

Answer (score 0):

Try this as per @Marc's suggestions,

```
grep 'Feb 1.*rambo' file |wc -l
```

In case, position of both strings are not sure to be as mentioned in question following command will be useful,

```
grep 'rambo' file|grep 'Feb 1'|wc -l
```

The **output** will be,

```
2
```

Here is what I tried,

[image]

Comment: nope. That's an "or" test. it'll return the "Feb 1...sandy" line, which is not what OP wants. `grep 'Feb1.*rambo'` would probably be better.

Answer (score 0):

Is Feb 1 always before rambo? if yes:

```
grep -c "Feb 1 .* rambo"
```

Comment: what if `rambo` appears first in the line?

Comment: Will this command work if some delimiter is also present between those two words?

Comment: Yes. But I assumed space is delimiter. Is it space or TAB?

Comment: It's a space and also other delimeter like ":" can also be present

Answer (score 0):

The awk solution is probably clearer, but this is a nice sed technique:

```
 sed -n '/Feb 1/{/rambo/p; }' | wc -l
```